# Way to get floating-point special values in CUDA?

Tags: cuda, floating-point, nvidia, nan

Is there any device functions in CUDA to obtain IEEE 754 special values like inf, NaN? I mean the stable way, not by some maths ops that could be optimized-out by compilers.

I only manage to find a device function called nan() that must take some unknown string argument.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

How about `CUDART_NAN` (double) and `CUDART_NAN_F` (float) defined in `/usr/local/cuda/include/math_constants.h` :

```
#define CUDART_NAN_F            __int_as_float(0x7fffffff)
#define CUDART_NAN              __longlong_as_double(0xfff8000000000000ULL)
```

and:

```
#define CUDART_INF_F            __int_as_float(0x7f800000)
#define CUDART_INF              __longlong_as_double(0x7ff0000000000000ULL)
```

Comment: The nan() function you found in CUDA is the nan() function as specified by the ISO C99 standard. I believe the same function is now part of C++11. Note that the double-precision version of this standard math function will be a lot slower than using the solution Robert pointed out, because it needs to parse a string argument to construct the numerical value of the NaN. The single-precision version, nanf(), is very fast since NVIDIA GPUs only support one canonical single-precision NaN, so that is what what the function returns.

Answer (score 1):

CUDA now has the nanf instruction in the maths library.

**device** float nanf( const char *tagp )

```
Returns "NaN"
```